# Get-ChildItem Zero Results Output

Tags: powershell, for-loop, get-childitem

I have an issue that I cannot resolve no matter which way I am wrapping it up.  I am including my latest code which is not giving me the desired outcome and the code for a solution that does work but for only one file at a time. I cannot work out how to loop through each of the files automatically however.

In a nutshell, I have a directory with many `CSV` files some of the entries within the `CSV`file have a negative value (-) I need to remove this minus sign in all instances.

Now what works is if I use the following (on a single file)

```
$content = Get-Content "L:\Controls\BCR\0001cash.csv" | ForEach {$_ -replace $variable, ""} | Set-Content "L:\controls\bcr\0001temp.csv"
```

What I am trying to do is iterate through the many thousand of these objects automatically and not have to refer to them individually.

I started with:

```
$Directory = "L:\Controls\BCR\"
$variable = "-"
$suffix = ".tmp"
```

To define the directory, minus symbol that I want to remove and the suffix of the file I want to change to...

```
$Files = Get-ChildItem $Directory | Where-Object {$_.Extension -like "*csv*"} | Where-Object {$_.Name -like "*cash*"}
```

Is obtaining each of the files that I wish to work with

And I am then working with

```
ForEach ($File in $Files) { Get-Content $Files | ForEach {$_ -replace $variable, ""} | Set-Content {$_.Basename + $Variable}
```

The results however are nothing...

At a loss?  Anyone???

```
$Directory = "L:\Controls\BCR\"
$variable = "-"
$suffix = ".tmp"


$Files = Get-ChildItem $Directory | Where-Object {$_.Extension -like "*csv*"} | Where-Object {$_.Name -like "*cash*"}

$process = ForEach ($File in $Files) { Get-Content $Files | ForEach {$_ -replace $variable, ""} | Set-Content {$_.BaseName + $suffix}



}
```

Comment: Hi, `Set-Content` writes content ***in*** the file. `Rename-Item` would rename it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the *wrong variable* in the `Get-Content` cmdlet (`$Files` instead of `$File`). Also You can simplify your script:

```
$Directory = "L:\Controls\BCR\"
$variable = "-"
$suffix = ".tmp"
Get-ChildItem $Directory -Filter '*cash*csv' | 
    ForEach-Object {
        (Get-Content $_ -Raw) -replace $variable |
             Set-Content {$_.BaseName + $suffix}
    }
```

Comment: Hey Martin thanks for your answer a lot cleaner than what I had written, I took some time to understand the -Raw which I had not seen before and the inclusion of two terms within the filter that again I had not known about so massive thanks here!   Your solution led me to a more elegant solution to what I was attempting purely by chance.  Cannot thank you enough!   I eventually used.

Comment: $Directory = "L:\Controls\BCR\"
$variable = "-"
$suffix = ".tmp"
Get-ChildItem $Directory -Filter '*cash*csv' | 
    ForEach-Object {
        (Get-Content $_ -Raw) -replace $variable | Set-Content $_ -Force
        }